# Unbind Function on element from loaded page

Tags: jquery, ajax, unbind

I've tried repeatedly to remove a function that is bound to an event using `unbind` and `off`, however it doesn't seem to work.

I've recreated this issue to the best of my ability on [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Wimbledon/9x15dhsr/1/), and this replication of my issue seems to be pretty accurate as to what I have on my website.

The Problem:
I have a website that operates on one page through the process of ajax calls/loads, and so, when I load a certain page, I am trying to unbind a function on that loaded page that is called on page load.
I'm sorry that this may not be clear to you so I hope the jsFiddle explains it more appropriately.

The remote page that I am trying to load refuses to turn a function off after the page has been loaded

Answer (score 1):

Alright - Multi Part here that may or may not be just a jsfiddle issue.

1) First, it's good practice to have a personal style guide. You might be running into some issue later on mixing bind / unbind with on / off. In this case I updated things to on/off to be consistnt:

- Checkpoint: http://fiddle.jshell.net/qde7ar5t/2/

2) `.load` can specify a "target" to load once the page downloads. It looks like `.load` of the base html is is currently inserting a new jquery script when you probably don't want that. This means that your "off" functions are actually binding to a whole new `window.jQuery` functions than the original `.on()` functions.

- Demo: http://fiddle.jshell.net/qde7ar5t/8/

3) You can fix this by specifying you only want to load `.alert` as the scope of what you're loading

- Demo: http://fiddle.jshell.net/qde7ar5t/9/
- Load Docs: http://api.jquery.com/load/

4) If you can't stop the scope in #2, you can just update your global `unbind` function to closure the original / `_$` instead.

Comment: I forgot to mention that my website requires the entire page to be loaded, not a specific element, so I can't necessarily target an element, it has to load the entire page unfortunately. So how would I go about updating my global unbind function to closure the original?

Comment: Hmm, the page load script is in an external js file and so it's impossible for me to wrap the two scripts, but I do appreciate the help I'm just going to assume it's a lost cause at this point